# Behavioural difference of if-if-else and if-elif-else in a while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, output, difference

I am unable to get my desired output when 'if-if-else' conditioning is used. However, using 'if-elif-else' works just fine. I have tried tracing but do not understand the reason for the difference in outputs. I am unsure why does it break out after just 1 execution for the 'if-if-else' case and why doesn't it perform like when 'if-elif' is used.

Here are the codes: they are exactly the same except 'if' is replaced with 'elif' on line 8

1.if-if-else

```
x = 1                                                
y = 0
while True:
    if (x is not None ) & (y%30!=0):
       y+=1
       x=5
       print("x=",x)
    if y%30==0:               #line8
       print("ENTERED y=",y)
       y-=29
    else:
       break
```

2.if-elif-else

```
x = 1
y = 0
while True:
    if (x is not None ) & (y%30!=0):
        y+=1
        x=5
        print("x=",x)
    elif y%30==0:              #line8
        print("ENTERED y=",y)
        y-=29
    else:
        break
```

Here are the outputs:

1.if-if-else

```
       ENTERED y= 0
       x= 5
```

2.if-elif-else

```
       ENTERED y= 0
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       ENTERED y= 0
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       x= 5
       ...(prints x=5 for another 29-4 =25 times)
       ENTERED y= 0
       ...(loops endlessly)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there's a difference! `elif` stands for `else if`.
When having another `if` after an `if` the second if will be checked regardless of the result you got from the first if.

When having an `else` or an `else if` (the key point is the else) the statement will be checked only if the first `if` condition turned out to be `False`.

Please note that when using the `if` alone in line 8 then the following `else` is "connected" to that second if, but when using `elif` all of the `elses` and `ifs` are "the same block". So in the second case since always it's either `y % 30 == 0` or `y % 30 != 0` (and x is not None) it will never reach the `break`!

Comment: Hi snatchysquid, thanks for the fast reply. 

I understand the difference between using else-if and if, but failed to notice that the if and else statements were connected(as you've mentioned in your last paragraph) which kept me thinking if I had misunderstood something about their differences.

Comment: So did you understand the process?

Comment: Yes, I see why it only executed once for the 1st case now. Instead of the intention of the program re-looping between the if and else-if statements.

Comment: Lovelyful! If this helped you consider upvoting/marking this answer as correct :)